# Accessing an enum in a different namespace

Tags: c#, enums, namespaces

I'm using C# in VS2005. I have a class library that contains several enums common to a number of different projects. When accessing one of these enums I have to specify the whole namespace path to the enum even though I have declared a 'using' directive to the namespace that contains the enum.

For example I have the following enum:

```
namespace Company.General.Project1
{
   public static class Rainbow
   {
    [Flags]
    public enum Colours
    {
      Red,
      Blue,
      Orange
    }
  }
}
```

Then in another project I have:

```
using Company.General.Project1;

namespace Company.SpecialProject.Processing
{
  public class MixingPallette
  {
    int myValue = Company.General.Project1.Colours.Red;
  }
}
```

Even though I have the 'Using' directive referencing the project that contains the class of the enum, I still have to write the enum longhand.
**Why can't I do the following...**

```
using Company.General.Project1;

namespace Company.SpecialProject.Processing
{
  public class MixingPallette
  {
    int myValue = Colours.Red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your enum isn't just in a namespace - it's a nested type. In fact, your sample "working" code wouldn't work, it would have to be

```
int myValue = (int) Company.General.Project1.Rainbow.Colours.Red;
```

(Not only do you need to include the `Rainbow` part, but there's also no implicit conversion from an enum to int.)

Make your enum a top-level type:

```
namespace Company.General.Project1
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Colours
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Orange
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to write:

```
using Company.General.Project1;

...

Colours x = Colours.Red;
int y = (int) Colours.Red;
```

(Note that to use `[Flags]` effectively, you should be assigning values explicitly, e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8...)

---

EDIT: I've been assuming you really do want to be able to use `Colours.Red` etc. You *can* keep your current structure, using a nested type, and just write:

```
Rainbow.Colours x = Rainbow.Colours.Red;
int y = (int) Rainbow.Colours.Red;
```

Unless you have a particular reason to make the enum nested, however, I wouldn't.

Comment: +1 - should be able to use "Rainbow.Colours.Red" as the shortened version, if kept within the Rainbow class.

Comment: That was his main question, why it didn't work while using was used. :)

Comment: I've moved the enum out of the static class and I can now access it how I wanted. Thank you. Apologies for making you do extra work - the code I posted was just example code to highlight the namespace situation I left out the bitwise values and int conversions to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your enums out of the static class - they can exist in their own right. So this would work:

```
namespace Company.General.Project1
{
  [Flags]
  public enum Colours
  {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Orange
  }
}

using Company.General.Project1;

namespace Company.SpecialProject.Processing
{
  public class MixingPallette
  {
    int myValue = (int)Colours.Red;
  }
}
```

But if you keep the enum within this static class, then it can only be referenced in that context:

```
using Company.General.Project1;

namespace Company.SpecialProject.Processing
{
  public class MixingPallette
  {
    int myValue = (int)Rainbow.Colours.Red;
  }
}
```